# AngularJS/Restangular indexed JSON data extraction

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, restangular

I've got and app that takes quote input (purity, weight, total), and it pushes to $scope.quote:

```
// Controller action //
$scope.quote.push({ 
  total: ((($scope.karat * $scope.spot) * $scope.percentage) / 20) * $scope.estimatedWeight,
  karat: $scope.karat * 100,
  description: $scope.description,
  actualWeight: $scope.actualWeight,
  estimatedWeight: $scope.estimatedWeight,
  percent: $scope.percentage * 100,
  spot: $scope.spot
})
```

and

```
// Factory //
app.factory('quoteFactory', function() {
  var quote = [];
  var factory = {};
  factory.getQuote = function () {
return quote;
  };
return factory;
})
```

and the post/save upon quote completion

```
$scope.save = function() {
  var now = $scope.getDate();
      $scope.quote.push({
        createdOn: $scope.getDate()
      })
    Restangular.all('quote').post($scope.quote).then(function(quote){
      $location.path('#/scrap')
    }); 
  };
```

When trying to access the quote JSON for list or edit I can't access all the information needed because of the JSON structure.

```
{
"0": {
    "total": 401.79040000000003,
    "karat": 74,
    "description": "Rings",
    "actualWeight": 12,
    "estimatedWeight": 11,
    "percent": 80,
    "spot": 1234
},
"1": {
    "total": 560.7296,
    "karat": 56.8,
    "description": "Test",
    "actualWeight": 22,
    "estimatedWeight": 20,
    "percent": 80,
    "spot": 1234
},
"2": {
    "total": 48.5625,
    "karat": 92.5,
    "description": "Testing",
    "actualWeight": 80,
    "estimatedWeight": 75,
    "percent": 70,
    "spot": 20
},
"3": {
    "createdOn": "2013-11-26T21:26:42.253Z"
},
"_id": {
    "$oid": "52951213e4b05f03172f14e7"
}
}
```

Each index represents a line item of the quote and the createdOn info.  What I'm trying to figure out is if there is a way to be able to access all the line item information without having to call each individual index?

I've looked into some lodash/underscore, thought about restructuring the backend...  Not really sure where to go from here.

[Complete project code at github](https://github.com/yahtaa/MSysInv)

Comment: How did you create the JSON? the indexes seem unnatural, if I ```JSON.stringify``` an array, it normally doesn't come with indexes included

Comment: Or more specific; where does that JSON come from? does the server read it? I would suggest fixing the JSON, not trying to read it despite its formatting being wacky

Comment: Perhaps since the factory is pushing into var quote = [] that is causing the indexing.  But if changing to an {} for quote what method would I use to replace $scope.quote.push()

Comment: But at the same time, if I lose the indexing, I would lose the ability to separate line items in a single quote offer.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is not much details available as to how your backend works or is handling the data I am assuming the problem is with generating the JSON.

What I would do is change the way Angular posts the data to the server, for example:

the Save function:

```
$scope.save = function() {
  var url = 'http:127.0.0.1:3000/url/you/send/your/data/to',
      json = JSON.stringify($scope.quote);

  $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: json,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  }).then(function(response) {
    $location.path('#/scrap');
  });
};
```

This will give you more control, and will make sure you control how the data gets turned into proper JSON, in this case using the `.stringify()` method of the `JSON` object.

I see from your comments that you are concerned with indexing; conventionally objects that sync with the server have a property `id` that represents their database id's NOT their client array index. This is a good way to keep the model data on the client a representation of the truth on your server side.

There are quite some libraries out there that help with this process client side, I would suggest - since you are using Angular already - reading into [Angular Resource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource).

NOTE: if you want to support older browsers with the `JSON.stringify()` method, make sure you use [Crockford's JSON2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js)

Comment: The back end is being handled by Restangular.